# Does CardDAV support contact groups?

Tags: contacts, address-book

Does CardDAV support contact groups/mailing lists, i.e. a feature to group several contacts into one group?

I searched the Internet for a while, but could not find a reliable answer. Seems some implementations use "categories" for that, but I'm not sure if that's the intended use.

Comment: It's a long standing question, and AFAIK the short answer is - No. One can do a tricks with CardDAV tags but... well it is a spike